# netsh advfirewall firewall com variable

Tags: variables, vbscript

Does anyone know any way to use a variable in the command to create a rule on the firewall? I'm using the code below, and it works if I have the door, but as we vary between doors, I would like to get the result typed in the input, but I'm not getting it.

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next 
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
If WScript.Arguments.length =0 Then
   Dim objShell
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
else
Dim oFS, oWS, oWN, oShell, Shell, Chave, Choice

Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim Input
Input = InputBox ("Enter the Port value", "New Door")
'Input = 2929
If Input = "" Then
MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
Else
MsgBox ("You typed :" & Input)
oShell.Run ("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”test” dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport= $Input")
'oShell.Run ("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”test” dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=Input")
'oShell.Run ("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”test? dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2929")
WScript.Echo "Changed port"
End IF
End IF
```

Comment: Try: `Call oShell.Run("netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name=""test"" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=" & Input)`

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.